# Regex won't capture past \n

Tags: python, regex, string

I've been trying to clean some data with the below, but my regex won't go past the \n. I don't understand why because i thought .* should capture everything.

```
table = POSITIONS AND APPOINTMENTS  2006  present Fellow, University of Colorado at Denver Health Sciences Center, Native Elder Research Center, American Indian and Alaska Native Program, Denver, CO  \n2002  present Assistant Professor, Department of Development Sociology, Cornell \n   University, Ithaca, NY   \n \n1999  2001
```

output = table.encode('ascii', errors='ignore').strip()

```
pat = r'POSITIONS.*'.format(endword)
print pat
regex = re.compile(pat)
if regex.search(output):
    print regex.findall(output)
    pieces.append(regex.findall(output))
```

the above returns:

```
['POSITIONS AND APPOINTMENTS  2006  present Fellow, University of Colorado at Denver Health Sciences Center, Native Elder Research Center, American Indian and Alaska Native Program, Denver, CO  ']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` does not match a newline unless you specify [`re.DOTALL` (or `re.S`) flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL).

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search('.', '\n')
>>> re.search('.', '\n', flags=re.DOTALL)
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x0000000002AB8100>
```

---

```
regex = re.compile(pat, flags=re.DOTALL)
```